# Check how many times a row repeats in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have some records in a table, with the columns: `id, link, title`.

Few rows in the db have the `link column` with the same value, and I want to know how for `link` how many rows have the same value.

I have an idea on how to do it but I think there is a much easy solution.

```
o = Repo.select(:link).distinct
o.each do |l|
  Repo.where(link: l.link).size
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at `group` in this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group).

Comment: select("link as link, count(*) as count").group(:link), thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment above, the `group` method will group the query based on selected parameter. So:

```
Repo.group(:link).count
```

will return a Hash such as:

```
{link1=> count_for_link_1, link2=> count_for_link_2 ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`Repo.select('count(*)').group(:link)`